# "system clock synchronized: no", flip it to yes

Tags: centos, redhat, fedora, rhel8, chrony

`# timedatectl` outputs

```
               Local time: Tue 2020-10-06 13:35:31 PDT
           Universal time: Tue 2020-10-06 20:35:31 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2020-10-06 20:35:30
                Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

`/etc/chrony.conf` is the default in RHEL 8 (with a preconfigured pool).

`# chronyc sources` outputs

```
210 Number of sources = 8
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? excalibur.prolixium.com       0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? paladin.latt.net              0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ronin.ruselabs.com            0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 2a00:7600::41                 0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 50-205-244-112-static.hf>     0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? time.cloudflare.com           0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 69.10.161.7                   0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ntp3.your.org                 0   9     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
```

`# systemctl status chronyd` shows `active (running)`, and no errors in the logs.

The displayed system time is correct.

So, given all these facts, why is it that I see `System clock synchronized: no`? How do I turn it to `yes`?

Comment: And why do I see stratum 0 in `# chronyc sources`? Also `# chronyc tracking` gives stratum 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chronyc sources` indicates that it does not have connectivity to any of the available NTP servers. This is what the `?` in the `S` column means, from the man page:

> This column indicates the state of the source.
>
> - *?* indicates sources to which connectivity has been lost or
>   whose packets do not pass all tests. It is also shown at
>   start-up, until at least 3 samples have been gathered from
>   it.

Check your Internet connectivity, host firewall, external firewalls, etc.

Comment: In fact, this is a playground server behind a NAT that doesn't allow port 123/udp in either direction.

Comment: And that's why you can't synchronize.

Comment: I'm now trying to synchronize 2 machines in the playground that I know can ping to each other and I just added the ntp service to their firewalld and designated one the source to the other.  If it was just a connectivity issue, this should work

Comment: yup. ? changes to * and no changes to yes.